# Should JUnit tests overlap?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, junit

I have made one test that checks if the answers on a question is added properly. I also have a update method test. But as you see in the update method you see that I check if the answer has been added before doing what the test is really supposed to do. Is this wrong? Shoud I assume that it works since I already have the case of adding answers covered by another test or should I make such asserts?

```
@Test
public void shouldAddAnswersToQuestion() {
    try {
        addAnswerToQuestion(new Answer("It is 3", false));
        addAnswerToQuestion(new Answer("It is 4", true));
        addAnswerToQuestion(new Answer("It is 5", false));
        addAnswerToQuestion(new Answer("It is 6", false));

        assertEquals(4, question.getAnswers().size());
    } catch (MultipleAnswersAreCorrectException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@Test
public void shouldUpdateAnswerInQuestion() {
    try {
        Answer answer = new Answer("It is 4", true);
        addAnswerToQuestion(answer);

        Answer answerFromList = null;

        answerFromList = question.getAnswers().get(0);
        assertEquals(answer, answerFromList);

        answer.setDescription("It is now 5 instead of 4");
        question.updateAnswer(answer);

        answerFromList = question.getAnswers().get(0);
        assertEquals(answer, answerFromList);
    } catch (MultipleAnswersAreCorrectException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A test should only assert on one bit of observable behaviour. Other behaviours that the test incidentally touches should generally be assumed to be correct, because we test for them elsewhere.

"One bit of observable behaviour" does not mean that you should only have a single assertion, but that you should only assert on one "thing" or one "unit of behaviour", for some value of thing or behaviour.

If I had written the `shouldUpdateAnswerInQuestion` test, then I would not have added the first assertion.

Answer (score 1):

To answer this, I have a question for you. If a regression happens and an answer is no longer added (assertion breaks), is it more clear if one test breaks, or two, (or by extension, 10,20, 30 or whatever)?

I personally think if a feature breaks exactly one test should fail.

Answer (score 0):

No and yes.

You can't, well shouldn't, assume in shouldUpdateAnswerInQuestion that addAnswerToQuestion passed. Perhaps that test will run next or in parallel or not at all...

However in your test of shouldUpdateAnswerInQuestion, checking that what you added was what you got back should be all that is needed.

Your issue seems to me, to be answer.setDescription("It is now 5 instead of 4");

Perhaps

```
answer.setDescription(String.Concate("It is now 5 instead of ", question.getAnswers().get(0));
```

would be better.

Comment: This should be Java, String.Concate looks like C#.

Comment: You understood what I meant didn't you?

Answer (score 0):

Redundancy in test coverage is good, because it means that your coverage will remain greater under maintenance.  Two tests that are testing the same code-path today might be testing different code-paths tomorrow.

That said, there are maintainability issues.  Maintaining a large test suite with n tests can cost O(n) programmer time each time you make sweeping changes.  If some tests are redundant and hard to maintain, you might be able to streamline development by getting rid of them.

If the additional test is not going to add much to maintenance overhead, then just add it.

If the old test is a maintenance headache, put in a comment that part of the test is redundant, so a maintainer can rid of the overlapping part instead of maintaining the whole thing.